# Do any books exist in Korean Hangul online for free?

Tags: resources

Do there exist any Korean etexts online, such as [Samguk Yusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samguk_yusa), in plain text format (i.e. not in PDF)? I saw [this](https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%EB%B2%88%EC%97%AD:%EC%82%BC%EA%B5%AD%EC%9C%A0%EC%82%AC) but I can't tell what is the actual underlying text, it's all intermingled with Chinese.

Comment: So are you looking specifically for historical texts ?

Comment: Well... you know, Samguk Yusa *is* written in Classical Chinese...

Comment: @LancePollard, would you mind if I show you a platform for free training on this?

Comment: @Lance, were you able to find anything? I've been quite curious too

Answer (score 1):

The Wikisource article you mentioned is not intermingled with Chinese. The Chinese part is the original, but they have been translated to Korean. You can just neglect the Chinese part and read the Korean part only. Then the whole contents should be covered.